# Traversing along Upper & Lower Siblings efficiently

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, tree-traversal

> [image: a simple demo]

Trying to build a plugin effect that will some what look better than this when its ready.

Note the numbers `0`, `1`, `2`.

They are simple indication of level the element currently is in. `0` denoting the top level and `2` the least. Check the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nmUeb/2/).

Every time I click on a column, it becomes the main columns *(thus gaining `0` as its level)* and rest of the columns are leveled using the same rule. If you see the snippet I am using to do that, it is very ugly.

```
$("li").click(function() {
    $(this).html(0);

    //denote the first level
    $(this).next().html(1);
    $(this).prev().html(1);

    //denote the second level
    $(this).next().next().html(2);
    $(this).prev().prev().html(2);    

    //denote the third level
    $(this).next().next().next().html(3);
    $(this).prev().prev().prev().html(3);    

    //denote the fourth level
    $(this).next().next().next().next().html(4);
    $(this).prev().prev().prev().prev().html(4);    
});
```

I absolute hate it. What if the number of my column grow, I am in trouble then. I need something neat to traverse up the tree structure (i.e like `.closest("li")`) and below as well. 
With every column, getting their specific level of markup once the main column changes.

Comment: As Felix is saying, you should change the question title as you are only interested in traversing siblings. Or we don't understand the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`prevAll` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) and [`nextAll` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/):

```
$(this).prevAll().each(function(i) {
    $(this).text(i+1);
});

$(this).nextAll().each(function(i) {
    $(this).text(i+1);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nmUeb/3/)

Btw. you are not traversing up or down the tree, you are always staying at the same level.

Comment: @Starx: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Isn't .next(), .nextAll() the traversing function of jquery? Anyways, they are working for my case. Thanks. BTW, is there a way to combine .nextAll() & .prevAll()?

Comment: @Starx: Yes, these are traversing methods, but you are not traversing the tree up or down (don't confuse the HTML representation with the actual DOM representation). All the `li`s are at the same level. Traversing "up" would be to go to their parent. I was thinking about a way to combine these too, but then computing the index would be more difficult. Depending on what you want to do, you might just want to get all siblings with `$(this).siblings()`.